# java string index out of bounds

Tags: java, if-statement, java-me, char

I have gone over and over this code and can't see where this is happening it doesn't happen every time it only happens if I run through post twice but I have tried getting rid of each of these in turn by commenting them out and that still gives the error but if I get rid of both my code works fine but they are necessary and they did work before. Any help is appreciated.

```
if(lines[i].length() > 10)
{
    if(lines[i].charAt(4) == '-' && lines[i+1].charAt(4) == '-')
    {
        lines[i] = "\nComment";
    }
}
if(lines[i].length() > 10)
{
    if(lines[i].charAt(4) == '-' && lines[i+1].charAt(4) != '-' && !lines[i-1].equals("\nComment"))
    {
        lines[i] = "\nPost";
    }
}
```

Comment: please include the full stacktrace.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? What's the value of `i`? What's the length of the array?

Comment: We need more surrounding code to tell you where the mistake is.

Comment: `lines[i+1]` may well not exist -> `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Can we see: (1) an example of input that you'd use? A dump of `lines[]`? (2) stack trace? Since a lot of the code you use is direct references to indexes its hard to tell if you're going out of bounds without the input. `.charAt(4)` could be out of bounds if `lines[i]` or `lines[i+1]` was never initialized properly. Are you stepping through in a for-loop? `lines[i+1]` would probably throw out of bounds on hte last iteration if you are.

Comment: it would be nice to know what i is. you're accessing lines[] with both i-1 and i+1 as the index, meaning if i is 0 or lines.length-1 at any point you'll get index out of bound. Is this in a for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not check

- that `lines[i+1]` exists,
- that `lines[i-1]` exists, and
- that the length of `lines[i+1]` is at least five.

This would break when `i` is zero or `lines.length-1`, or when one of the prior/next lines has less than five characters.

Comment: Thanks for that got it working now just checked if `[i+1]` is > 10

Answer (score 2):

in `lines[i+1].charAt(4)`: what if `lines[i+1]` has less than 5 characters?

Answer (score 1):

You have only tested the length of `lines[i]`, whereas you are accessing `lines[i+1].charAt(4)`, that might give you that issue, if its length is less than 5.

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of all of your variables before using them. You vary the index but you don't do the neccesary checks (null, length and array index checks).

In particular when accessing:

```
lines[i+1]
```

and

```
lines[i-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are we sure lines +1 and -1 are in the 10 char range?